# Is there a way to apply AOP advice only to a given instance of a type (e.g. singleton bean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have three beans of the same type, defined with Java-based config:

```
@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplateLocal")
@Primary
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateLocal(@Qualifier("dataSource") BasicDataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplateEk5_contragent")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateEK5Contragent(@Qualifier("dataSourceEK5_contragent") BasicDataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplateEk5_contract")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateEK5Contract(@Qualifier("dataSourceEK5_contract") BasicDataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

And I would like to apply AOP advice only to one of them. I try to do it as follows (although, I've already understood that it's wrong):

```
    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(..))")
public void namedParameterJdbcTemplateUpdate() {}

@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary)")
public void beanAnnotatedAsPrimary() {}

@Around("namedParameterJdbcTemplateUpdate() && beanAnnotatedAsPrimary()")
```

Such pointcut expression does not match at all, and if I remove the "&&.." part, it works for all 3 of the beans.

Is there a way to do it with AOP pointcut expressions ?

I think that if I implement a child class of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and apply a custom annotation on it, it should work; however, I'm interested to learn the other approaches as well.

Comment: actually, as it turns out, if I inherit that class, I don't need AOP for my task at all; I just have to override the necessary method and implement necessary behavior there

Comment: still, there're cases when this is not very much feasible; so, I would still love to see the answers for the original question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [bean() pointcut](https://spring.io/blog/2007/09/24/the-new-bean-pointcut). On your example will be:

```
@Around("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(..)) && bean(jdbcTemplateLocal)")
public Object jdbcTemplateUpdate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {}
```

or

```
@Around("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(..)) && bean(jdbcTemplateEk5_contragent)")
public Object namedParameterJdbcTemplateUpdate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {}
```

Be aware that you have a bean of type `JdbcTemplate` in `getJdbcTemplateLocal`

Also, your example doesn't work because the first `@Pointcut` is on execution of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update`, and the second one is on `@Primary` annotation. And there is no `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update` method annotated with `@Primary`. The method that has `@Primary` is `getJdbcTemplateLocal`.

Comment: Thanks ! that my "idea" was not working, I've already worked out. I did not know about "bean" pointcut expression, thanks!